# Getting a too much iteration done before the next frame error Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

```py
class StackLayoutExample(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 50):
            b = Button(text=str(i + 1), size_hint=(0.2, 0.2))

            self.add_widget(b)


<ScrollViewExample@ScrollView>:
    StackLayoutExample:
        size_hint:1,None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

Basically I want to make a scroll bar made up of the stack of 100 buttons whoch I looped through

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `size_hint`. Keep in mind that setting the  `size_hint` for a widget means that it changes its size when its parent size changes. But, in your case, that parent is the `StackLayoutExample`, and you have it set to do `height: self.minimum_height`. So, what happens is that every time you add a `Button` to the `StackLayoutExample`, the size of the `StackLayoutExample` changes, which triggers a change in the size of each `Button` which triggers a new calculation of `self.minimum_height` for the `StackLayoutExample`, changing its size, which again triggers changes in the `Buttons` (due to `size_hint`).

The fix is to eliminate the part of the `size_hint` that affects the `minimum_height` of the `StackLayoutExample`. Just set an explicit `height` for those `Buttons` to avoid that recursion:

```
class StackLayoutExample(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 50):
            b = Button(text=str(i + 1), size_hint=(0.2, None), height=50)  # set an explicit height
            self.add_widget(b)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It had been bugging me for hours